# Better alternative to writing Switch Statements in VueJS filter component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, switch-statement

I have a Vue Component I created that does a simple filter. I am using BootstrapVue.

My question is, I am aware that in JavaScript Switch Statements aren't always recommended due to difficult debugging and nested errors but what would a better alternative to something like this look like?

```
 computed: {
    products() {
      switch (this.selectedFilter) {
        case "all": {
          let products = [];
          let min = 0;
          for (let i = 0; i < productItems.length - 1; i++) {
            min = i;
            for (let j = i + 1; j < productItems.length; j++) {
              if (productItems[j].order < productItems[min].order) {
                min = j;
              }
            }
            let temp = productItems[min];
            productItems[min] = productItems[i];
            productItems[i] = temp;
          }
          productItems.forEach(product => {
            products.push(product);
          });
          return products;
        }
        case "subscriptions": {
          let products = [];
          productItems.forEach(product => {
            if (product.type == "recurring") {
              products.push(product);
            }
          });
          return products;
        }
        case "onetime": {
          let products = [];
          productItems.forEach(product => {
            if (product.type == "onetime") {
              products.push(product);
            }
          });
          return products;
        }
        case "purchased": {
          let products = [];
          productItems.forEach(product => {
            if (product.purchased) {
              products.push(product);
            }
          });
          return products;
        }
        case "unpurchased": {
          let products = [];
          productItems.forEach(product => {
            if (!product.purchased) {
              products.push(product);
            }
          });
          return products;
        }
        default:
          return "Product";
      }
    }
  },
  data() {...}
```

Comment: The use of `switch` seems fine but there's a lot of duplication between the branches. Perhaps just create a predicate function within each branch and move the actual filtering logic to after the `switch`. Using `filter` instead of `forEach` would also help.

Comment: Thanks @skirtle but I guess I am looking for a complete alternative suggestion to the switch, as in what would the most elegant solution today look like.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using switch statements, both yesterday and today. Whoever told you that they're "difficult to debug and give nested errors" doesn't know what they're talking about.

Comment: I dont think you can really go away from the switch statement when you are not filtering every time on a common property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `switch` statements is great in the context you've shown, there's nothing wrong with that bit. What could use some work is transforming the results into a usable format.

Using [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) would benefit you greatly:

```js
switch (this.selectedFilter) {
  case "all":
    return productItems.slice().sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  case "subscriptions":
    return productItems.filter(product => product.type === "recurring");
  case "onetime":
    return productItems.filter(product => product.type === "onetime");
  case "purchased":
    return productItems.filter(product => product.purchased);
  case "unpurchased":
    return productItems.filter(product => !product.purchased);
  default:
    return [];
}
```

As a small aside, it's good practice to return a consistent data type from your function, an array in this case, hence the changed default case. If you need to show a placeholder when there are no items, you can handle that in your template declaration instead.